# Selenium Webdriver: Date field is getting populated with the string sent but later change to some other date as soon as focus is changed

Tags: java, excel, date, selenium, webdriver

I need to enter date in the date field in my application. I have made a java code to do so every day. So what I do is simply enter the date and data in a spreadsheet column. And using apache poi and selenium webdriver, I will fetch it and enter in the date field in the application. The date field has a calendar popping out when ever a focus is set there. I simply bypassed it by clearing the default date in the field and entering the date from excel sheet as string.
The above logic was working fine. But now the date I enter is 12/06/2015 (US time zone) and the date entered there is also the same. But when the focus is set to the next field the date changes to 12/16/2015. I am not getting any idea about why it happens and of course how can it be avoided....out of clues..

```
    private static void setBloodGlucose(String vitalname, String date,
        String time, String vitaldata) throws Exception {
    Log.info("Entering vital data: " + vitalname);
    KeyActions.click(OR, "btnGearBloodGlucose");
    KeyActions.clickById(OR, "btnBloodGlucose");
    KeyActions.waitFor("4");
    KeyActions.input(OR, "txtBloodGlucoseDate", date);
    KeyActions.input(OR, "txtBloodGlucoseTime", time);
    KeyActions.input(OR, "txtBloodGlucose", vitaldata);
    KeyActions.clickById(OR, "btnBloodGlucoseSave");
}

    public static void waitFor(String data) throws Exception {
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(Long.parseLong(data));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.error("Not able to Wait --- " + e.getMessage());
        DriverScript.bResult = false;
    }
}

    public static void input(Properties OR, String object, String data) {
    try {
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Constants.TIMEOUT);
        Log.info("Entering the text in " + object);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(OR
                .getProperty(object))));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(object))).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(object))).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(object))).sendKeys(
                Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"), data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.error("Not able to Enter the text in " + object);
        Log.error(e.getMessage());
        DriverScript.bResult = false;
    }
}

   public static String getCellData(int rowNum, int colNum, String sheetName)
        throws Exception {
    try {
        ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(sheetName);
        Cell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(colNum);
        DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();

        String celldata = df.formatCellValue(Cell);
        // String CellData = Cell.getStringCellValue();
        return celldata;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.error("Class Utils | Method getCellData | Exception desc : "
                + e.getMessage());
        DriverScript.bResult = false;
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you provide the code you are using to retrieve the date from the spreadsheet, and the code you are using to populate the date field in your application?

Comment: Provide the code you have tried with

Comment: Please check the code added...